# Как сделать подключение стороннего кода через composer в yii2

Tags: yii2, composer

Есть установленный через `composer` `yii2`.
Есть в корне сайта папка с самописной библиотекой.

структура:

```
var\www\ 
        |
        -------yii2
        |
        -------mylib
```

В mylib лежит единственный файл lib.php

Какую конкретно последовательность нужно сделать для того что бы в `контроллере` я мог вызвать методы из lib.php?

Answer (score 2):

В composer.json

```
    "autoload": {
        "files": [
            "mylib/lib.php"
        ]
    },
```

после чего в консоли

```
composer dump-autoload
```